# What is jealousy and how to deal with it?

Tags: jealousy

Which kind of feelings are included in jealousy and how can we get rid of jealously ?

Comment: If you want to know what the definition of Jealousy is you should look at online dictionaries and if you want to get rid of jealousy using duas etc, I suggest you edit your question so you reformat it and make the question on how to get rid of jealousy in Islam.

Comment: What to do about it is answered here: [If a person is feeling jealous, what should they do?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/23441/17163).

Comment: I'm missing the connection to Islam in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Jealousy is a fear of loss and a fear of not being good enough. It's a loss of internal self value...

In the eyes of Allah we all are valuable .. we go through these challenges so that we too learn our value...

A flower does not look at other flowers and fear its  beauty ,
No more than a a Pine tree fears the strength of an Oak tree...

In the acceptance of self we find peace away from what is jealousy

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. We are not a typical an internet forum. Therefore we expect answers to be well elaborated, see "[how to answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)" for more information. I strongly recommend you to take our 2 min. [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about this site and the stack exchange model.

Comment: @Sarai Herst-Hill spiritually inspired.May Allah reward you.